# How do I setup content approval for only a sub-folder of a document library?

Tags: permissions, approval-process

I'm trying to setup a new drawing approval system at work.

As of right now, we create a new Teams channel for each project in the "PROJECTS" team. This create a new subfolder in the "Documents" library in sharepoint called "XXX-X Name of the project". Inside of this folder I have one named: "XX-Drawing"

I'd like to use the content approval feature only inside the XX-Drawing folder as I don't want the rest of the project file to be inaccesible until someone aprove them.

Is there a way to either automatically aprove everything outside my target folder or enable this feature only in the correct subfolder? (PROJETS/Documents%20partages/XXX-X Name of project/XX-Drawing)

Answer (score 0):

Place it inside it's own document library.  Content approval needs to be enabled on document library level.  It sounds like your created a folder only.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm trying to work around a system that's already in place. Creating a new team channel only add a folder to the default document library as far as I can tell.